# Are pre-releases not getting security updates?

Tags: security, beta

I got a new computer a couple of weeks before the expected Trusty release date, so to save my the trouble of first installing Precise and then upgrading, I installed Trusty Final Beta. Now I see that even though older releases got a new OpenSSL version last night to address the heartbleed bug, there's no OpenSSL update for Trusty.

What's the deal with that? Aren't pre-releases getting critical security fixes? Who is supposed to want to test a system when testing means not getting critical security fixes?

Comment: Ubuntu distributions are based on Debian releases, which come in "stable", "testing" and "unstable" versions. LTS versions of Ubuntu are based on "testing" releases while non-LTS versions are based on newer "unstable" releases. Currently, the security update you want is in version 1.0.1.g, which is in the "unstable" release as of yesterday. Therefore, 14.04 LTS would normally not get this update until 1.0.1.g goes from "unstable" to "testing". However, I imagine an exception can and will be made for such a high-priority fix, but I'm not familiar with the procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that 14.04 did receive an update for OpenSSL, but I didn't see it earlier, because ([according to Timo Jyrinki](https://twitter.com/timojyrinki/status/453489972151328768)) security updates for pre-releases propagate through the usual mirror system (slowly) instead of becoming available right away via the repo hosted on security.ubuntu.com.